# WP7 playready customdata

Tags: windows-phone-7, playready

I have a wp7 app that will play Playready protected live smooth stream.
Before hitting the protected URL, the customData field needs to be set.
I could not find, where to set the customdata in Wp7, whereas in Silverlight app it can be done using below code...

```
LicenseAcquirer la = new LicenseAcquirer();
la.ChallengeCustomData = "MY_CUSTOMDATA_HERE";
PlaylistItem playlistItem = new PlaylistItem();
playlistItem.LicenseAcquirer = la;
```

But `LicenseAcquirer` class does not have `ChallengeCustomData` field in `WP7`. 
How can then the custom data be set?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 is based on a very old version of Silverlight (v3). This version did not have support for sending the PlayReady CustomData element in license requests. I believe what you are trying to accomplish is not possible.